# Embed plot from child process (Qprocess) script into Qgraphicsview in main parent process- main thread

Tags: python, plot, pyqt5, qprocess

I have created a pyqt5 GUI from Qtdesigner with a Qgraphicsview window to display plots/images. Trying to run a script that has some plots that can print sequentially on the pycharm window.

I have attempted to print the script inside a Qprocess, the script runs, and the text output from the print statement is appended to the QPlainTextEdit.

Here is my unsolved challenge that I need help with.

- Whenever I run the main parent Python file in pycharm, the text from the script is appended in the GUI output text field with signal/slot Qtimer configuration as desired, but the plots display in the pycharm scientific mode sciview plot display.
- How can I redirect the plot to display sequentially on the Qgraphicsview in the GUI?

```
def Run_Script(self):
        """
        Read any stdout data available from the process and displays it in the output log window.
        :return:
        """
        
        arg00 = 'python'
        arg0 = 'test_exit.py'
        self.proc = QProcess()
        self.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText("Executing process..") 
        #########################################################
        self.proc.started.connect(self.time.start)

       

        self.proc.start(arg00,[arg0])
        self.proc.readyRead.connect(self.dpret)#dpret slot connect to signal
        self.proc.readyRead.connect(self.pbar)
        self.proc.started.connect(self.mgr_proc)`


def dpret(self):

        cursor = self.plainTextEdit.textCursor()
        cursor.movePosition(cursor.End)
        # Here we decode the QByteArray 
       cursor.insertText(str(self.proc.readAll().data().decode(CP_console))) 
        self.plainTextEdit.ensureCursorVisible()

        # load image to graphicsview/plot
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        pixmap_2 = QtGui.QPixmap()

        # here, am stuck how to load plot images in the stdout stream ??
        pixmap_2.loadfromdata(stdout)
        item_2 = QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap_2)
        self.scene.addItem(item_2)
        self.graphicsView.setScene(self.scene_2)


    ####################################################
    #Content of test_exit.py
    
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure
    import numpy as np

    data = [-0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5,1.5, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 3.1, 3.2]

    plt.hist(data, bins=5, range=[-1, 4], histtype='step')
    print("first output on QPlainTextEdit...............")
    plt.show()

    data = [-0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5,1.5, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 3.1, 3.2]

    plt.hist(data, bins=5, range=[-1, 4], 
    histtype='step',edgecolor='r',linewidth=3)
    H, bins = np.histogram(data[:6], bins=5, range=[-1, 4])
    H+=np.histogram(data[6:], bins=5,range=[-1, 4])[0]

    plt.bar(bins[:-1],H,width=1)
    print("second output on QPlainTextEdit.............")
    plt.show()
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Why is it necessary to use QProcess? Why don't you just import the test_exit module and then embed it in the GUI? something like https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt_sgskip.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. You mean embed the script output plots in the Qgraphicview ? How ? Running the script inside the main thread,takes a long time to process.So i planned to run the script in its own child process with a button widget.

Comment: How to get the plots to show up sequentially seperated by Qtimer in the Qgraphics view ?